# I'm not getting any output in python. Here's my code for approximating e^x:

Tags: python

I'm not getting any output in python.  Here's my code for approximating e^x:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n != 0:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
    else:
        return 1

def calc(u):
    x = (-2)
    sum(((x ** i) / (factorial(i))) for i in range(0, u+1))
    return

calc(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try printing the result.

```
print(calc(10))
```

You also need to fix your sum.

```
x =  sum(((x ** i) / (factorial(i))) for i in range(0, u+1))
```

and then

```
return x
```

Comment: thanks that helped! the only problem is i got a value of none

Comment: You also need to `return x`

Comment: @JordanPagni.  Just a friendly reminder that if my answer answered your question, you can click the checkmark next to the vote buttons to mark it as "accepted."

Answer (score 0):

Use return with value:

```
return sum(((x ** i) / (factorial(i))) for i in range(0, u+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the sum instead of just using return.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n != 0:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
    else:
        return 1

def calc(u):
    x = (-2)
    return sum(((x ** i) / (factorial(i))) for i in range(0, u+1))

print(calc(100))
```